# anonymize my RCurl web scraping using a pool of randon proxies

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to build a web scraper with `R` using the `RCurl` package. 
 
The problam is that once I download once the site blocks my ip.
Is it possible to build a pool of proxies so each download is from a different proxy using `RCurl`?
This is my code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
theurl <-paste("http://www.yad2.co.il/Nadlan/rent.php?City=%E9%F8%E5%F9%EC%E9%ED&Neighborhood=&HomeTypeID=&fromRooms=&untilRooms=&fromPrice=&untilPrice=&PriceType=1&FromFloor=&ToFloor=&EnterDate=&Info=",i,sep="")
url<-htmlParse(theurl)
tables <- readHTMLTable(url)
a<-tables[lapply(tables,length)>19]
a<-na.omit(as.data.frame(a[1],ncols=20))
```

(I cut out only the part of code doing the scraping)

If there is another way to be ablr to scrape a lot of data with out being blocked I would be glad to hear!

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with Israeli IP law, but it sounds like you just asked folks to help you [violate that site's terms of service](http://www.yad2.co.il/Takanon.php#11). As such, I won't provide code, but you can absolutely do what you suggest. Read up on how to set proxies in R, go find a server provider that allows illegal activity and prepare for a cease & desist letter from that site.

Comment: @eliavs : did you find a solution to your question?